# exc_bad_access on uibutton click using Xcode 6 and Swift language

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, exc-bad-access

I am trying to add another sub view on click of button.

First view is created using storyboard and button action is working fine.
But when I add new viewcontroller's view as subview and click on button, application crashes with exc_bad_access on iPhone Simulator.

here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad() 
    let datePick : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 218, 216))
    datePick.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    datePick.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    datePick.layer.borderWidth = 5

    let actionView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 216, datePick.frame.width, 50))
    actionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
     self.view.addSubview(datePick)

    var cancelButton : UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    cancelButton.frame =  CGRectMake(datePick.frame.width-80, 5, 60, 40)
    cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: "cancelPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    actionView.addSubview(cancelButton)

    var doneButton   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    doneButton.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 5, 60, 40)
    doneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:",forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
     self.view.addSubview(actionView)
    actionView.addSubview(doneButton)

   // datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 218, 216);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("Button tapped")
}

func cancelPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    println("Cancel Clicked!!!")

}
```

IBAction Method called from first viewcontroller's view is :

```
  @IBAction func dateSelectClicked (sender:AnyObject){

    var datePicker = DatePicker()
    datePicker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

    let isfinished : Bool = true
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.0 , options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { datePicker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height-266, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)}, completion: {(isfinished) in println("finished")})

}
```

Comment: When enabled Zombie Error log is :*** -[TableViewComponent.DatePicker performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f95184fa350 where TableViewComponent is project name & DatePicker is viewcontroller's name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem :

As provided in question, DatePicker viewcontroller was adding as :

```
 var datePicker = DatePicker()
```

on click of button.(func dateSelectClicked)

So this is the problem with creating instance of DatePicker.

We need to create it as property outside method as :

```
 Class firstViewController :UIViewController {
      var datePicker = DatePicker()
   }
```

and use as property in method self.datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Change this 2 lines from:

```
self.view.addSubview(actionView)
actionView.addSubview(doneButton)
```

to:

```
actionView.addSubview(doneButton)
self.view.addSubview(actionView)
```

Comment: And your error is coming when you click the button? Or on ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes it is coming on button click. If I remove cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: "cancelPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) and doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:",forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) there is no error. Code works sometime.

Comment: Try to uncomment all other this except the donebutton. Then add the donebutton direkt to your view and press the button again.

Comment: tried commenting whole code and added done button to self.view. Still same error

Comment: Error is coming when I am adding this viewcontroller's view as subview to another view. If I am adding button directly to anotherview,click is working.

Comment: You mean when you are using another UIView its not working. But when you are only add to button to self.view, everything is fine?

Comment: Yes there are 2 viewcontroller. When I click button on first.. this second view controller view is added as subview. When I add button to first view, it works but if i add it to second it crashes.basic requirement is to show datepicker with done & cancel button on selection on a button in first view